# How to use shared memory with Concurrent module?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm using Concurrent module to parallelize a function, but it is slow.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    images = executor.map(gen_images, paths)
```

Can I use shared memory to expedite this? The arrays returned by the function are numpy arrays.

EDIT: The function to parallelize is this:
the function involves both reading and processing. But way more processing than reading. So, I'd say it is CPU bound

```
def gen_images(heads):
    N = len(heads)
    # we will be taking 34 slices from the head
    images = np.zeros((N * 34, 328, 286), dtype='uint8')
    counter = 0

    for i in tqdm(heads):
        name = i
        # reading the associated head
        insert_path = os.path.join(name, 'insertion_metadata.txt')
        model_path = glob(os.path.join(name, 'head', '*' + '.dat'))[0]
        data_, specs_, insertion_ = read_head(model_path, insert_path)
        for z in range(-17, 17):
            images[counter ,: ,:] = plot_slice(data_, specs_, insertion_, return_image = True, z_slice=z)
            counter += 1
    return images
```

Comment: You're using a thread pool. Threads already share memory automatically.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Then how do you explain the fact that whether I use multiprocessing or multithreading the speed is the same?

Comment: Who knows. Maybe you screwed up. Maybe the two approaches' different sources of overhead happened to work out close enough to each other that you didn't see the difference. We can't tell from this.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I've gone ahead and added the function. I don't see how Concurrent module is makring use of shared memory. Each instance of the function is returning a separate output, those get accumulated in a list and returned.